# Hive Partitions - How to delete null or hive_default_partition

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am facing a problem with hive default partition (null partition) in hive.
I will explain the situation briefly here.. I have a hive main table and data ingestion is happening to that table everyday. but somehow when data is ingested into the hive table something went wrong and partition is showing _hive_default_partition_ or in my understanding it is null partition.

i need to delete the partition from hive tables. (it is external table)...

I am using hive version 1.1 and CDH version 5.4.8 ..

I tried the below syntax and its not working for me..

```
alter table "tablename" drop partition(partn='_hive_default_partition_);

alter table "tablename" drop partition(partn<'1');

alter table "tablename" drop partition(partn = 1);

alter table "tablename" drop partition(partn='0');
```

i tried all the above steps and nothing worked..

Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 7):

The way that worked for me was altering the datatype of the partition column, deleting the partition and changing it back.

Considering that you are comparing the partition to an int in the question, I assume that is the column datatype to start with, however this should work regardless of the datatype you start with.

`-- Change the column type to string
ALTER TABLE tablename PARTITION COLUMN (partn STRING);`

`-- Drop the offending partitions
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PARTITION (partn='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');`

`-- Change the column type back to int
ALTER TABLE tablename PARTITION COLUMN (partn INT);`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the directory from hdfs and run msck repair table.

From shell: `hadoop fs -rm -r ..../partn=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__`

From hive shell: `msck repair table table_name;`

Comment: This only works if your partition column datatype is already string.

Comment: Yes you are right. Newly noticed that the table is external. I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in 3-steps

1. Remove partition data from the HDFS using
   hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash  eg.

`hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/<db-name>/<table-name>/<partition-name>=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__`

2. Open hive client and run

   `set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;`
3. Run this in hive client

   `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <db-name>.<table-name>;`

Comment: AFAIK, MSCK REPAIR adds partitions, but it doesn't remove existing partitions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alter table `tablename` drop if exists partition (partn<>'');
```